# Referencing a dialog in a listener before dialog has been instantiated by dialog builder

Tags: android, dialog

I'm trying to build a nice little quick dialog box that lets the user choose a sync interval with the main server.

```
public void editSyncInterval(View view)
{

final AlertDialog intervalDialog;
final CharSequence[] items = { "1 minute", "2 minutes", "5 minutes", "10 minutes", "30 minutes" };

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Select Sync Interval");
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item)
    {
        switch(item)
        {
            case 0:
                //save
                intervalDialog.dismiss();
                break;
            case 1:
                //save
                intervalDialog.dismiss();
                break;
            case 2:
                //save
                intervalDialog.dismiss();
                break;
            case 3:
                //save
                intervalDialog.dismiss();
                break;
        } 
    }
});
intervalDialog = builder.create();
intervalDialog.show();
}
```

However, on the 4 lines that are `intervalDialog.dismiss();`, I get the following (rather expected) error: `The local variable intervalDialog may not have been initialized`.

I'm assuming that you need to call builder.create *after* you have already set up the listeners etc, but in which case - how do you reference the dialog itself - since you have not instantiated it yet?

Comment: Why don't you use the dialog parameter of the onclick method? if contains the dialog instance that will be created when builder builds it --> be equal to then available intervalDialog. Alternatively, you can make intervalDialog variable global, e.g. place it into activity members list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You get `DialogInterface dialog` as parameter into listener. You can call `dismiss()` on it.*

You should use

```
 dialog.dismiss();
```

instead of

```
intervalDialog.dismiss();
```